# Limit of the form $0/0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do I find $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos(\sin x)-\cos x}{x^4}$$ I tried rewriting $\cos$ in the form of $\sin$ and then applying $\sin x/x$ form, but it doesn't work out. Does it?

Comment: Just apply L'hospital's rule

Comment: I don't see how the above edit was approved (see edit history if desired)--it completely changes the nature of OP's question. If the OP wants an approach without L'hospital, then this information should go into the question.

Comment: LOL I just saw the tag "proof sans l'Hopital"

Comment: @Vim I know. That made me chuckle a little bit too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Taylor series could be useful. Start with $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Then use the Taylor series of $\cos(y)$; for the first term in numerator replace in the result $y$ by $x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ and for the second term in numerator replace in the result $y$ by $x$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But could you find the final answer. My answer is not matching with what is given.

Comment: What is given ?

Comment: Given answer is 1/2

Comment: This is then wrong ! What did you get by yourself ?

Comment: I think I got 1/6 or 1/4.(I don't remember)

Comment: $1/6$ is fine. How can't you remember ? Having memory problems at my age could be acceptable ... not at your ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Apply L. Hospital's Rule since the limit is $\frac{0}{0}$. If the resulting form is again $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, continue the same process. 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Comment: Doesn't the equality hold only when $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists?

Answer (score 0):

First use Taylor series $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$$ to get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$$ Next we can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos \sin x - \cos x}{x^4}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2\sin\left(\dfrac{x+\sin x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{x-\sin x}{2}\right)}{x^4}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}2\cdot\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{x+\sin x}{2}\right)}{\dfrac{x+\sin x}{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x+\sin x}{2x}\notag\\
&\,\,\,\,\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{x-\sin x}{2}\right)}{\dfrac{x-\sin x}{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x-\sin x}{2x^3}\notag\\
&=2\cdot 1\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)1\cdot\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{6}\notag
\end{align}